# How to search JSON object based on Ids using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filter

In my web application, when the initial load AJAX call gives following JSON string.

```
[  
   {  
      "UserId":10259,
      "FullName":"jhno doil",
      "SupervisorId":"10165"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10405,
      "FullName":"Adam mark",
      "SupervisorId":"10261"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10400,
      "FullName":"belly barra",
      "SupervisorId":"10161"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":16224,
      "FullName":"silvester",
      "SupervisorId":""
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10416,
      "FullName":"Arnetta Chatcho",
      "SupervisorId":"10179"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10244,
      "FullName":"Ashanti Bueti",
      "SupervisorId":"10165"
   }
]
```

How Can write filter function or LINQ query to select matching records based on passing SupervisorIds string? Can I write LINQ with JQuery?
this function should accept comma separated SupervisorIds string and filter the matching JSON based on that.

```
function usersBasedOnIDs(SupervisorIds){


}
```

This is how I call the function,

```
usersBasedOnIDs("10165,10179,10161");
usersBasedOnIDs("10179,10161");
usersBasedOnIDs("10165");
```

And if I pass Empty string to the function `usersBasedOnIDs("")` all the JSON object should return without any filtration.

As a clear **ex:1** if I call fuction as `usersBasedOnIDs("10165,10179,10161");`

This JSON should be returned,

```
[  
   {  
      "UserId":10259,
      "FullName":"jhno doil",
      "SupervisorId":"10165"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10400,
      "FullName":"belly barra",
      "SupervisorId":"10161"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10416,
      "FullName":"Arnetta Chatcho",
      "SupervisorId":"10179"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10244,
      "FullName":"Ashanti Bueti",
      "SupervisorId":"10165"
   }
]
```

**ex: 2** if I call fuction as `usersBasedOnIDs("10165");`

```
[  
   {  
      "UserId":10259,
      "FullName":"jhno doil",
      "SupervisorId":"10165"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10244,
      "FullName":"Ashanti Bueti",
      "SupervisorId":"10165"
   }
]
```

Comment: There's not much worth of searching in [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Comment: I think you are confused about the technologies you're asking about. _JSON_ is **J**ava**S**script **O**bject **N**otation — a way to represent JS objects/arrays as plain text. Once you have a JSON string you generally want to `JSON.parse(theString)` to get an actual Javascript Object/Array. You can then manipulate that with normal Javascript code; no need for jQuery or LINQ.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `split` to split the string, `filter` by SupervisorId and `includes` for checking item in array.

You may need use `JSON.Parse` to convert string to object before using.

More about function at

Includes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes
Filter

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
function usersBasedOnIDs(SupervisorIds){
  let Supervisors = SupervisorIds.split(",");
  let result = data.filter(c=>SupervisorIds.includes(c.SupervisorId));
  console.log(result);
}
```

```js
var data = [  
   {  
      "UserId":10259,
      "FullName":"jhno doil",
      "SupervisorId":"10165"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10405,
      "FullName":"Adam mark",
      "SupervisorId":"10261"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10400,
      "FullName":"belly barra",
      "SupervisorId":"10161"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":16224,
      "FullName":"silvester",
      "SupervisorId":""
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10416,
      "FullName":"Arnetta Chatcho",
      "SupervisorId":"10179"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10244,
      "FullName":"Ashanti Bueti",
      "SupervisorId":"10165"
   }
];
//"10165,10179,10161"
function usersBasedOnIDs(SupervisorIds){
let result = [];
if(SupervisorIds == "") {
  result = data;
}else{
  let Supervisors = SupervisorIds.split(",");
  result = data.filter(c=> c.SupervisorId != "" && SupervisorIds.includes(c.SupervisorId));
}
console.log(result);
return result;
}

//usersBasedOnIDs("10165,10179,10161")
//console.log(usersBasedOnIDs("10165"))
usersBasedOnIDs("")
```

Comment: @Hien Nguyen Is this Linq? or pure JQuery?

Comment: It is pure javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: @Hien Nguyen when i call the function as `usersBasedOnIDs("10165");` which print this json record also `   {  
      "UserId":16224,
      "FullName":"silvester",
      "SupervisorId":""
   }`

Comment: I updated condition for filter data.filter(c=> c.SupervisorId != "" && SupervisorIds.includes(c.SupervisorId));

Comment: @HienNguyen when I pass empty string `usersBasedOnIDs("");` I also need to retrieve all the records,which means original json

Comment: Hello sir, can I pass the result value to another function. In your answer, we need to call the function like this (`console.log(usersBasedOnIDs("10165"));`) to see the result. without that can I use console log inside `usersBasedOnIDs` function?

Comment: @h  Your answer have some problem sir, suppose when the JSON data have       **"SupervisorId":"10",  "SupervisorId":"101"** when Is search `(usersBasedOnIDs("10165")` its also shows **"SupervisorId":"10",  "SupervisorId":"101"**  as well? why its happening so

Comment: Your answer have some problem sir, suppose when the JSON data have "SupervisorId":"10", "SupervisorId":"101" when Is search (usersBasedOnIDs("10165") its also shows "SupervisorId":"10", "SupervisorId":"101" as well? why its happening so

Answer (score 2):

Here's your function, using an array is better in these situations :

```
function usersBasedOnIDs(SupervisorIds){

 //SupervisorIds is an Array !
 const data = YOUR DATA;
 var newData = [];
 if(SupervisorIds && SupervisorIds.length > 1){
   SupervisorIds.forEach(e => {
     if(SupervisorIds.includes(e.id))
      newData.push(e)
   });
   //if no match found, return an empty array
   return newData;
 }else{
   //No filter
   return data;
 }
}
```

Comment: is this pure js or JQury?

Comment: @thomsan pure JS

Answer (score 2):

```
const data = [
    {
        "UserId":10259,
        "FullName":"jhno doil",
        "SupervisorId":"10165"
    },
    {
        "UserId":10405,
        "FullName":"Adam mark",
        "SupervisorId":"10261"
    },
    {
        "UserId":10400,
        "FullName":"belly barra",
        "SupervisorId":"10161"
    },
    {
        "UserId":16224,
        "FullName":"silvester",
        "SupervisorId":""
    },
    {
        "UserId":10416,
        "FullName":"Arnetta Chatcho",
        "SupervisorId":"10179"
    },
    {
        "UserId":10244,
        "FullName":"Ashanti Bueti",
        "SupervisorId":"10165"
    }
];

function SearchById(id, field = "SupervisorId") {
    if (id === "") return data;
    return data.filter(value => {
        if(Array.isArray(id)) {
            return id.indexOf(value[field]) !== -1;
        }
        return value[field] === id;
    });
}

SearchById("10165");
SearchById(["10165", "10179"]);
// Search By Other Field
SearchById(10259, "UserId");
```

i suggest passing multiple ids by array but if you want the old way you can use this function

```
function SearchById(id, field = "SupervisorId") {
    if (id === "") return data;
    return data.filter(value => {
        if(id.split(',').length > 0) {
            const ids = id.split(',');
            return ids.indexOf(value[field]) !== -1;
        }
        return value[field] === id;
    });
}
```

Using jQuery:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "UserId":10259,
        "FullName":"jhno doil",
        "SupervisorId":"10165"
    },
    {
        "UserId":10405,
        "FullName":"Adam mark",
        "SupervisorId":"10261"
    },
    {
        "UserId":10400,
        "FullName":"belly barra",
        "SupervisorId":"10161"
    },
    {
        "UserId":16224,
        "FullName":"silvester",
        "SupervisorId":""
    },
    {
        "UserId":10416,
        "FullName":"Arnetta Chatcho",
        "SupervisorId":"10179"
    },
    {
        "UserId":10244,
        "FullName":"Ashanti Bueti",
        "SupervisorId":"10165"
    }
];
function SearchById(id, field = "SupervisorId") {
    return jQuery.grep(data, function(value) {
        if(id === "") return data;
        if(typeof(id) === "string" && id.split(',').length > 0) {
            const ids = id.split(',');
            return ids.indexOf(value[field]) !== -1;
        } else if(Array.isArray(id)) {
            return id.indexOf(value[field]) !== -1;
        }
        return value[field] === id;
    });
}

console.log("single", SearchById("10165"));
console.log("multiple array", SearchById(["10165", "10179"]));
console.log("multiple split", SearchById("10165,10179"));
console.log("empty", SearchById(""));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Read more about [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Is this pure JS or JQuery?

Comment: This I tested,but when I call funtion with empty string, which only returns `{UserId: 16224, FullName: "silvester", SupervisorId: ""}` This reocrd only, As I in the question said, I need to pass all the record when I pass empty string

Comment: @thomsan you want the function to use jQuery?

Comment: no sir, this is fine, if you can give an answer with JQuery, It would help to improve my knowledge. :) anyway thanks

Comment: @thomsan the answer has been updated with jQuery function.

Comment: @thomsan your welcome, can set the answer as the corrent one if it solves the issue, or upvote the answer?.

Comment: Okay sure sir, and I have one more question, How can print result inside `SearchById()` function with a console.log, without return its value. and if u can please give me a contact no or anything else. I have a bit of complex thing to ask from you, if u can pls give me